# index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'doc_type'

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, doctype

```
mapping = {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "Id_centro":{ "type": "keyword" },
            "RFC":{ "type": "text" },
            "Razon_Social":{ "type": "text" },
            "Entidad_Federativa":{ "type": "text" },
            "Tipo_De_Centro":{ "type": "text" },
            "Nivel_Centro":{ "type": "text" }
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el mapeo del indice creado, para agregar el mapeo se utiliza la siguiente linea

es.index(index="centro", id=1, body=mapping)

El mensaje de error es:

```
TypeError: index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'doc_type'
```

Elasticsearch version 8.5.0

Comment: you need to use `_doc` in your index request

Comment: what your python elasticsearch client version ?